# React Router 5 - history.push() won't render component - no errors

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to use `useHistory()` and `useRouteMatch()` and `history.push()` to render new component and pass the data down from `ProductCard` to that new `BeerDetails` component as props. `history.push()` changes the URL but nothing is rendered on the page. Same happens when I use `withRouter` and access `history` and `match` from props. Can anyone help me out please? Thanks!!!

```
const ProductCard = ({ beer }) => {
  //REMOVED STUFF FOR BREVITY  

  let match = useRouteMatch({
    path: "/:beerId",
    url: "/",
  });

  let history = useHistory();

  const { name, tagline, abv, first_brewed, image_url, price, id } = beer;
  return (
    <div className="product-card">
      <div className="product-card-inner">
        <div
          className="product-info-container"
          onClick={() => history.push(`/${id}`)} // THIS ONE SEEMS TO WORK
        >
          <h1 className="beer-name">{name}</h1>
          <p className="beer-type">{tagline}</p>
          <p className="beer-alcohol">{abv}%</p>
          <p className="first-brewed">First brewed: {first_brewed}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="beer-image-container">
          <img src={image_url} alt="beer" />
        </div>
        <div className="price-container">
          <h1>£{price}</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="form-container">
          <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
            //REMOVED FOR BREVITY
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      {match ? <BeerDetails beer={beer} /> : null} // THIS IS NOT DOING ANYTHING
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductCard;
```

I was trying to follow this guide: 
https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v5-1/

Comment: can you `console.log(match)` and see what it's value is after history.push gets called?

Comment: yes, it says ```null```. So the path does not match at all?

Comment: I've never used `useRouteMatch` so I'm not sure what it does but yeh if it's returning `null` you'll need to debug that. I've just read the docs, are you sure you need to return an object? what about doing `let match = useRouteMatch('/:beerId')`?

Comment: I have the same problem right now. Have you found a solution?

Comment: yes, I have. In my case, the routes were not set up properly. I ended up putting a `<Route path={"/:beerId"} component={BeerDetails} />`  in my App.js and it worked. I did not need `useRouteMatch()` in the end, I simply used useHistory() in the child component as above and it works.